# html registration form input box contains description

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css

I would like to make a registration form that contains the text within the form and only when you start typing the text disappears from the form. The only solution i have found is using css when the description text disappears as soon as you click on the box.

Comment: use `placeholder` attribute.

Comment: You mean placeholders? The thing is not all browsers support them, so you could create a lookalike with javascript too.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `placeholder` attribute. The placeholder disappears the second the user starts typing.

**Here is an example of usage:**

```
<form action="demo_form.asp">
  <input type="text" name="fname" placeholder="First name"><br>
  <input type="text" name="lname" placeholder="Last name"><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SimplyAzuma/fd82P/)

Keep in mind that the placeholder attribute of the input tag is not supported in Internet Explorer 9 and earlier versions.

Answer (score 0):

The `placeholder` attribute can be used on inputs, but some browsers handle it's functionality in different ways, for example, while Chrome and Firefox keeps the placeholder text visible until a user hits a character, Internet Explorer makes it disappear as soon as the input filed is in focus state.

Browser support for the `placeholder` attribute [is pretty wide](http://caniuse.com/#search=placeholder), although if legacy browser support is of concern, I'd suggest a simple JavaScript solution [such as this](http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/cross-browser-html5-placeholder-text).

Comment: facebook has a similar form on their login page, how would they go about it to optimise it for all the browsers ?